# findFragmentByTag() returns null on existing fragmentTag

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an `Activity` with a `FragmentContainer` that will show only one of two `Fragment`s.
By clicking on a `Button` of the first `Fragment` (`CreateTasksListFragment`), it is possible to show the other one (`CreateTaskFragment`).
When the user clicks on that button, `CreateTasksListFragment` gets hidden and a new instance of `CreateTaskFragment` is showed. Then, `CreateTasksListFragment` will be shown (by clicking on a button of `CreateTaskFragment`), and `CreateTaskFragment` has to be deleted.
The problem is that when I try to get the last instance of `CreateTasksListFragment` from the `FragmentManager` to show it again, even if I got its tag correctly by calling `getBackStackEntryAt()`, `findFragmentByTag()` **returns null**.
I don't think there're pending transactions, so probably I'm making another kind of mistake.
If you know better ways to achieve this goal, even without using this approach, please share them.

Here's the code interested by the issue:

CreateTasksActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    ...

    CreateTasksListFragment fragment = new CreateTasksListFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    setCurrentFragment(fragment, CreateTasksListFragment.TAG);
}

/**
 * Sets new fragment
 * @param fragment
 */
public void setCurrentFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.create_tasks_fragment_container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(fragmentTag)
            .commit();
}
```

CreateTasksListFragment.java

```
mNewTaskFabButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Task task = new Task(mTasks.size() + 1);
    mTasks.add(task);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(CreateTaskFragment.TASK_EXTRA, task);
    CreateTaskFragment fragment = new CreateTaskFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    // Replacing fragment with the fragment to create a single task
    getParentFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .hide(CreateTasksListFragment.this)
            .add(R.id.create_tasks_fragment_container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
});
```

CreateTaskFragment.java

```
mCreateTaskButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...

        FragmentManager fm = getParentFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment;

        String fragmentTag = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 2).getName(); // -2 since it starts counting from 0 and we need the second-last transaction
        Log.d("log1", fragmentTag);
        fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
        Log.d("log2", String.valueOf(fragment == null));
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .remove(CreateTaskFragment.this)
                .show(fragment)
                .commit();
    }
});
```

Log

```
2021-05-13 21:19:44.952 20865-20865/* D/log1: CreateTasksListFragmentTag
2021-05-13 21:19:44.952 20865-20865/* D/log2: true
```

The tag is the same I've used when I put the first transaction on the backstack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` you get back from `fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 2).getName()` is the `name`, you passed to `addToBackStack(String name)`. That's an entirely separate concept from the tag associated with a fragment.

If you want to set a tag associated with a fragment, you need to set one as part of your `replace()` call using the version that [takes a tag](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#replace(int,%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.create_tasks_fragment_container, fragment, fragmentTag)
        .addToBackStack(fragmentTag)
        .commit();
```

Note: you should **never** mix a fragments transactions that use `addToBackStack()` with transactions that do not use `addToBackStack()` as this will break the behavior of `popBackStack()` and the system back button (which assumes you have not changed any of the fragments since the last `addToBackStack()` transaction).